# Setting the type of an object a custom binder would apply to in a vNext application?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How would you set the type of the object you want the binder to apply to e.g:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(Person), new PersonModelBinder());
```

in a vNext application?

I can see that ModelBinders.Add has 3 overloads,

```
1) IModelBinder
2) ModelBinderDescriptor
3) Type
```

but I'm not sure how to translate the old code to this new code? Basically I want this kind of thing:

```
    services.AddMvc().Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.ModelBinders.Add(typeof(Person), new PersonModelBinder()));
    });
```

Thanks! btw, [I have looked here as well](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ModelBinders.Add).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems indeed like a gap in MVC 6. For now you will have to write the code directly in your binder.

```
 public Task<bool> BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
 {      
    if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(Person))
    {
        var value = // get the value
        bindingContext.Model = value;

        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }

    return Task.FromResult(false);
 }
```

[Here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/9468d741ee344c89ae6087b3336b258eb9cdd807/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ModelBinding/Binders/HeaderModelBinder.cs#L21-L26) and [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/d00c7ef59723fa2d7d5a544b9a831b73eb397c12/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ModelBinding/Binders/CancellationTokenModelBinder.cs) is a similar code used in the framework to implement `[FromHeader]`

[Here](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/1724) is a link to an issue tracking bringing back a similar overload to MVC 5.

Comment: I was trying to avoid this. Thank you for the issue tracking link though, I'll look out for it!